# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED: how to show the cause

Tags: linux, networking, command-line, strace

I am running an application (over and over again in a for loop) which is very heavyweight. I attempt to start the application via a python script.

Sometimes when I do that, I get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Note: I am also running this on a grid machine which has several users with several processes running. If I run this application on my local machine (several times) I do not get this error.

My instinct is telling me that since the application is heavyweight, the "server" side of the application which should start right after the client is not starting on time and is being delayed.

Another hint which also points me to this direction is that I measure the time it takes for the application to start, it varies between 10 to 32 seconds.

Is there any suggestion of how I can prove that this is actually the scenario which is happening? Any tracing/process tools I can use for this?

Comment: Are you able to add logging to your application? If the client calls `connect` before the server calls `listen`, or if the server doesnt call `accept` often enough and the accept queue gets too large, the client will get a connection refused error.

Comment: no I cant :( I don't have the source.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick that's interesting though, the accept queue gets too large, how can that happen? Is that many processes performing an accept?

Comment: It's the opposite: not enough accepts on that socket are being done compared to the number of inbound connections. When a server calls `listen`, it also specifies the length of the queue. Then it either loops, or creates a couple of processes that loop, calling `accept`.

Comment: The typical way to get connection refused, though, is for there to be no listener on that port on the server's system. The server should start, and call `listen`, before any clients try to connect to it.

Comment: You might try `strace -f -e trace=network yourpythoncommand` and watch the sequence of listen and connect calls.

Comment: Mark thank you ill try the strace command.